# Switched to the new dashboard convert array pointer objects to array json object

Tags: parse-platform

On the old dashboard Data Browser my pointers stored in an array looked like this:

[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Example","objectId":"4rRzh2w1Z2"}]

On the new dashboard Data Browser it converted to this:
[{"objectId":"4rRzh2w1Z2"}]

This crash many of my cloud code methods with this error:
Result: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'get'

and this is because when trying to access a pointer that i have included in cloud code method i get back a JSON object and not the retrieved pointer object.
Even if i use the ".id" i get an error because now there is a JSON object with the key objectId.

Please note that if rolling back to the old dashboard the JSON object doesn't convert back to a Pointer.

This looks like a serious bug, does anyone encountered such behavior?
Please assist before it reached production app.
Currently i have tried it on my development environment. 
Thanks

Comment: According to facebook developer bug report it's a bug that they fixed and will be pushed on the next dashboard update. In the meanwhile use the old dashboard.